# What was said in this movie at 27:20

Tags: verbos

This old western, I believe the man speaking to the woman was telling her to "leave us", or something to that effect, but the word he used sounded like "dispensanae" 
Can anyone tell me what word was used and if in fact it was Spanish?
https://youtu.be/RitGeeDfERY?t=1635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La locución que dice en la película, es "**Dispénseme**", y tiene el mismo valor que otras parecidas como "Discúlpenos" (un momento), "Excúseme", "Excúsenos", "Perdón", "Perdónenos", "Concédanos" (un minuto), "Exonérenos" (libérenos un momento de su presencia)...

Answer (score 3):

*Dispénseme* = "dispense usted a mí", from the verb [dispensar](https://dle.rae.es/dispensar), meaning *excuse me* in this context.